# How would you say in short

Tags: phrases, abbreviations

How would you say in short that this question or point is no longer actual and you did not think about it.
Something like "out of the agenda?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply say ***“no longer on the agenda”***.

Answer (score 5):

[*Moot*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moot) is another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

That particular point is *Invalid*, *Void* or *Null* ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[redundant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/redundant)*, *[immaterial](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/immaterial)* or *[irrelevant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/irrelevant)*?